# PHP - Can A String Of Text That Looks Like An Array (but is not that data type) Be Converted To Array w/o str_split()/explode(), etc?

Tags: php, arrays, string

Weird scenario I have to admit but it is actually relevant for me, so here goes.

**This is a curiosity question** since I have a better way to do this already.

I am creating a remote file for other developers to read (file_get_contents) and update. I know I can do this with JSON or creative use of `explode()` or `str_split()`, but was wondering if the following was possible.

If you have a text string formatted such that it "looks like" an array (but in PHP's eyes is not actually cast as an array):

```
//the following string represents the entire contents of the text file myfile.txt

array('key_1' => 'string_1', 'key_2' => 'string_2' ..... 'key_n' => 'string_n');
```

The string values (eg 'string_1') can literally contain any character...no exceptions. Is there any way that the text file can be read with e.g. `file_get_contents()`:

```
//this is the remotescript.php file

$arrayString = file_get_contents('path/to/myfile.txt');
```

and then you, the script writer, literally cast this as an array? (where the type and key => value pairs are set) That is:

```
$x = someFunction($arrayString);

// this returns ----> $x = array('key_1' => 'string_1', 'key_2' => 'string_2' ..... 'key_n' => 'string_n'); 

print_r($x); // outputs  ---->  Array([key_1] => string_1 [key_2] => string_2 ..... [key_n] => value_n)
```

In a bad attempt I tried casting the string using (array):

```
$string = file_get_contents('path/to/myfile.txt');

$x = (array)$string;
```

but this only creates one key where the value is the literal string from the text file.

Comment: Well as you already said your best option is probably to use `json_decode()`. (You could of course save it into a file like this: `<?php return array(...);` then include it and save it in a variable: `$var = include "file";`)

Comment: @Rizier123...yes going to just JSON it then json_decode($str, 1)

Comment: Looks like you can almost do it with [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), but the source file would need a return (see Example #5)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$x = print_r($string, true);
```

Comment: Thanks but it is still a string. Try this: echo gettype($x);